# What is the best SharePoint column type to store latitude and longitude inside our custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, column, administration

What is the best SharePoint column type to store latitude and longitude inside our custom list?

Comment: A simple addition, if you want to put the latitude and longitude in the same column, you can use the single line of text type.

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT no i am going to store them inside separate columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have below two options for storing location related data in SharePoint online modern experience lists.

1. **Location** column: The location column allows you to add rich location data from Bing Maps or your organization directory to any SharePoint list or library. So, if you want to store complete address based on bing maps, you can use this type of column in your list.

   Read more about location column at: [Add Location Details to SharePoint Data and Content](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/add-location-details-to-sharepoint-data-and-content/m-p/284875).
2. **Number** column: If you want to store only latitude and longitude in your list, you can use two number columns in the list to separately save the latitude and longitude data.

Use either of above available column types in SharePoint online modern lists based on your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried the Location column type,, but most of the addresses are not there... i need the addresses to locate specific location not a general location like street name ... I am working for a project in the middle east and can not autocomplete most of the addresses... so not sure if Location column type will be useful for us

Comment: You can use number columns for latitude and longitude then